# JSON to Map<String> conversion for every primitive data type

Tags: java, json, jackson

The purpose of this code is to convert unknown number of parameters with unknown number of values into the `Map<String, List<String>>` (key - parameter name, value - list of possible parameter values), assuming that every kind of type would parse to String.

The problem is that numbers and other formats are not parsing into String, and `jsonField.getValue()` is not a *value node* (`jsonField.getValue().isValueNode()` returns `false`) so I cant use `jsonField.getValue().asText()` since it returns `null`.

My approach:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.ListOrderedMap;

public ListOrderedMap<String, ArrayList<String>> convertParamsFromJson(String jsonParams) throws IOException {

    ListOrderedMap<String, ArrayList<String>> convertedParams = new ListOrderedMap<>();
    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsFromJson = convertFromJson(jsonParams).fields();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    while (fieldsFromJson.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, JsonNode> jsonField = fieldsFromJson.next();
        String paramName = jsonField.getKey();
        String paramValue = jsonField.getValue();
        if (jsonField.getValue().isArray()) {
            convertedParams.put(paramName, mapper.convertValue(paramValue, ArrayList.class));
        }
    }

    return convertedParams;
}
```

input:

```
{
"firstParam":[1],
"secondParam": ["a","b","c","d"],
"thirdParam": [1,2,3],
"fourthParam":[true,false]
}
```

expected output:

```
  <[MapEntry[key="firstparam", value=["1"]],
    MapEntry[key="secondparam", value=["a","b","c","d"]],
    MapEntry[key="thirdparam", value=["1","2","3"]],
    MapEntry[key="fourthparam", value=["true", "false"]]]>
```

output:

```
  <[MapEntry[key="firstparam", value=[1]],
    MapEntry[key="secondparam", value=["a", "b", "c", "d"]],
    MapEntry[key="thirdparam", value=[1,2,3]],
    MapEntry[key="fourthparam", value=[true, false]]]>
```

Comment: giving a brief look at the jackson docs, either use a custom `ObjectMapper` or set the default one to use custom deserialization rules to always map to string even if json has different type. How that is achieved, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `Jackson` library converts `JSON` primitives to suitable types. Consider below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"firstParam\":[1],\"secondParam\": [\"a\",\"b\",\"c\",\"d\"],\"thirdParam\": [1,2,3],\"fourthParam\":[true,false]}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, List<Object>> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
        map.forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.print(k + " => ");
            v.forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " (" + i.getClass().getSimpleName() + "), "));
            System.out.println();
        });
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
firstParam => 1 (Integer), 
secondParam => a (String), b (String), c (String), d (String), 
thirdParam => 1 (Integer), 2 (Integer), 3 (Integer), 
fourthParam => true (Boolean), false (Boolean),
```

But we can force to convert list items to `String` by providing a type we need to achieve by using `TypeReference`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"firstParam\":[1],\"secondParam\": [\"a\",\"b\",\"c\",\"d\"],\"thirdParam\": [1,2,3],\"fourthParam\":[true,false]}";

        TypeReference<LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>> mapOfStringListsType = new TypeReference<LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>>() {};
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, List<String>> map = mapper.readValue(json, mapOfStringListsType);
        map.forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.print(k + " => ");
            v.forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " (" + i.getClass().getSimpleName() + "), "));
            System.out.println();
        });
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
firstParam => 1 (String), 
secondParam => a (String), b (String), c (String), d (String), 
thirdParam => 1 (String), 2 (String), 3 (String), 
fourthParam => true (String), false (String),
```